# Well-formedness of hypersurfaces in weighted projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Consider a weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}_{a_1, \dotsc, a_r}$ and assume it is well-formed i.e. each $r-1$ of the $a_i$ are coprime. Let $g \in \mathbb{K}[T_1, \dotsc, T_r]$ be a weighted homogeneous polynomial and write $d := \deg(g)$. We call the hypersurface $X := V(g) \subseteq \mathbb{P}_{a_1, \dotsc, a_r}$ *well-formed* if $X$ does not contain any $2$-codimensional singular orbit of $\mathbb{P}_{a_1, \dotsc, a_r}$.

One of the standard references for weighted complete intersections is [Iano-Fletcher](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwicwPaP_KXaAhXMzqQKHSkrCMgQFjAAegQIABAz&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.warwick.ac.uk%2F~masda%2FUnpub%2FCPR_book%2FFletcher.ps&usg=AOvVaw0lJthJy3QAhQZ_zosLQfCL). There 6.10 says that $X$ is well-formed if and only if
$$ \gcd(a_i;\; i \neq i_1, i_2) \mid d $$
holds for all $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq r$.

I don't see why this is true. For example, consider $\mathbb{P}_{1,1,4,6}$ and $g = T_1^2 + T_2^2 + T_1 T_2$. Let $Z$ be the torus orbit of $[0,0,1,1]$. Then $Z$ is 2-dimensional singular orbit due to $\gcd(4,6) = 2 \neq 1$. However we have $Z \subseteq X$ because $g$ depends only on the first to variables.

Could you give me a reference for a proof and/or a hint what I'm doing wrong?